# How to select (highlight) text in Chrome app

Tags: highlight, google-chrome-app

I'm playing with Chrome app and find it very interesting.

But I wonder why how to select text inside a div in Chrome app.

I tried but it seemed not work.

Anyone knows the problem?

Thanks!

PS: This app read a text file, then output the result to a div.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default CSS is slightly different in apps, as defined in [platform_app.css](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/renderer/resources/extensions/platform_app.css?view=markup). You will need to add CSS to enable selection:

```
-webkit-user-select: text
```